# How to store output of a file content in a variable using batch script

Tags: arrays, list, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I have file named abc.txt with content:

```
Ryan is an engineer.
Nikola is a data engineer.
Mike is doctor.
```

Now I have created one script which will display the content of file:

```
@echo off
set /p file="Please enter file Name: "
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (%file%) do (echo %%a)
pause
```

And I am getting output as:

```
Ryan
Nikola
Mike
```

Now, what I want is that **I want to store or assign Ryan to one variable, Nikola to one variable and Mike to one variable so that I can use those variable for my further operations**.

So, can someone please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Note: I want this thing to be purely achieve using script not by powershell or any other tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2delims=: " %%a in ('findstr /n . %file%') do set "name[%%a]=%%b"
set name
```

See `for /?` documentation and `findstr /?` documentation.

`findstr` finds all lines that contain a character (default is regular expression provided = `.`) and `/n` numbers them in the format `serial:linecontents`. Using `:` and <kbd>space</kbd> as delimiters, token 1 becomes the line number and 2 the first word after, up to the space.

Build the variable from the parts and show result.